# How to update jmeter version easily?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, auto-update

I just got info that jmeter new version released its 2.12. I am using 2.11.

Can anyone help that how can I update my jmeter version easily? OR I need to delete old version and replace new?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a cron job /batch job for downloading the newest version of Jmeter from repo.
This will download the new copy of Jmeter everyday or at scheduled period and will replace with old one.

Generally this job is not so frequent and not required in general load testing assignments unless you are JMeter contributor or tester or JMeter enthusiast.
For regular purpose manual download and replace is enough.